# How to log SAML response

Tags: saml-2.0, pingfederate

I am able to configure IDP and SP adapters successfully. After establishing connections between them, how to see the generated SAML response? Where do they reside in the ping Federate folder?

And in order to set up one system as IDP and the other as SP, I am running tomcat on both the systems. If I hit system A from System B, I am able to see the default apache page. But if I want to access an SP resource (say system B), it should automatically redirect to IDP for authentication. How do I do that?

Can anyone please help?

Thanks,
Aswini J

Comment: Can you clarify how you have things setup for the 2nd part of your question? It's not exactly clear how you have integrated with PF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the actual SAML messages in the server.log file in PingFederate. So ../pingfederate/log is where those live.

Comment: I am able to see the SAML response. For Example, let us consider if you need to sign in to access yahoo. First, you would hit the yahoo url (SP), it should redirect to IDP for authentication. Once you are authenticated, you will have access to the yahoo page. For this, SP send the authentication request over HTTP Redirect binding. I want inputs for it. I know this is SP-initiated SSO. Once I am done with my configurations, how I will deploy those configurations on the server? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Ian noted, and you confirmed - you can find the logs in /pingfederate/log. The lion's share of the entries will be in server.log, and will include encoded and unencoded AuthnRequests and Responses, while running in loglevel "DEBUG".

For the second question, there are two ways that you can do SP-initiated SSO with PingFederate (well, there's many more, but two *common* ways). Both will involve one of our integration kits.

The first that I recommend is our [Agentless Integration Kit](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/AIK12/Agentless+Integration+Kit). I find this kit is one of the simplest to integrate. You don't have to install anything on your application, and just have to be able to parse out JSON-formatted messages. Your application picks up those messages directly from PingFederate, using a one-time-use reference ID carried to your application by the browser, which, I feel, is a bit more secure than cookies or whatever.

The second kit is our [Java Integration Kit](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/JIK252/Java+Integration+Kit). This kit does use the OpenToken standard, which can be passed either via cookie, POST, or REDIRECT, and is an installed agent.

Both of these kits support SP-Init SSO (and SLO), along with the usual IdP-init. I suggest you read up on them using the links provided, and determine which one works best for you.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Is java Integration kit to be used if our target application is a java application? Because, when I read about open token adapter, I came across this. Since, our end application is not a java application, I thought "Java Integration kit" is unnecessary. Is my assumption right?

Comment: We have a number of integration kits available - Java, .net, PHP, etc. Having said that, though, as I noted before, the one I would recommend is the Agentless. It's easy to implement. Get a token, and POST it to the PF server, get attributes back.